# After deploy site on LocalHost IIS unable to access some folder's page

Tags: asp.net, iis

I had deploy my site on localhost for testing locally and i have folders structure inside my project like >>

```
Masters Folders >> upto 20 aspx page
Jobs Folder     >> upto 10 aspx page
Reports Folder  >> upto 15 aspx page 
UserAuthentication Folder  >> upto 5 aspx page

i'm able to aaccess all pages from masters, jobs and userauthentication folder but unable to access Reports page inside reports folder
```

Answer (score 0):

on iis Right click on Reports folder
Edit Permissions -> Security
check the permission users wise **Read & Execute** enabled or not

Comment: i tried that things but not worked  for me i gave full permission